# Function that will leave the smallest occurrences at the bottom of stack

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to write a stack so that all of the occurrences of the smallest element are at the bottom of the stack, while the order of the other elements stays the same. For example, if I have the stack [4,3,1,5,8,1,4] it will become [4,3,5,8,4,1,1], but my problem is that the order changes
so i will get something like this[4,5,3,4,8,1,1]

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void minstack(stack<int> &s)
{

stack<int> t1,t2;
int count=0,min;
if(!s.empty())
    {

      while(!s.empty())
      {
          if(s.top() <min)
            { min=s.top();
                count=0;
                }

          t1.push(s.top()); s.pop();
          count++; 
      }
for(int i = 0 ; i<count;i++)

{
    s.push(min);
}

 while(!t1.empty())
      {
          if(t1.top()!=min);
          { s.push(t1.top());
              }
          t1.pop();
      }
}
}
int main()
{
    stack <int> s;
    s.push(4);
        s.push(3);
    s.push(1);
    s.push(5);
    s.push(8);
    s.push(1);
        s.push(4);
minstack(s);
while(!s.empty())
{
    cout<<s.top()<<" "; s.pop();
}

}
```

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Have you considered `std::stable_partition` ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition

Comment: You want to rearrange the stack, and the problem is that the order changes?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes exactly and i cant use stable_partition

Comment: @Matcha_boy98: And *why* can't you use `std::stable_partition`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea. First we'll need to find the smallest element of the stack. Define a temporary stack `t`. We'll now pop all elements one by one from `s` and push them into `t`. At the same time, keep track of the minimum value `min` and the number of times it has been encountered so far in the popping process in `count`. Once this is done, notice that you'll have the reverse order of elements in `t` and have `min` and `count`. Now we'll push `count` number of elements of value `min` back into `s`. Then start popping and pushing from `t` to `s` except for the elements which equal `min`.

Comment: Hi i am still facing an issue i get the same order but the lowest occureness increased

Comment: @Matcha_boy98 you must be popping and pushing from `t` to `s` without checking for `min`. Once you pop an element from `t`, only push it in `s` if it's not equal to `min`.